# I think I may have inadvertantly deleted/uninstalled some crucial packages on my Kali Linux OS

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Okay, so I'll make this quick, but start at the beginning. I have had a few Linux OS before, including having Kali twice so I know a bit about Linux. Apache was my original problem. Well before, I could enter

```
root@kali:~# service apache2 start
```

and then successfully navigate to local host in my browser and access my Apache server.

But with my current installation of Kali, I couldn't get it to connect to the server on local host. So earlier, I typed in

```
service --status-all
```

and found apache2 was running. I figured remove and purge it and try a fresh install. So I entered

```
apt-get --purge remove apache2
```

and said yes to continue. Then it started removing and purging a bunch of GNOME packages including something about desktop. But I didn't catch it until too late because I looked away for a min (my luck).

Now, I type in

```
apt-get upgrade
```

and it says

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
(long section I won't include right now on account of convenience)
Use 'apt auto-remove' to remove them.
```

Well in that long section was most of my packages from air crack and BEEF to hydra and wire-shark. What I'm worried about is if it may have somehow deleted any crucial OS files like GNOME desktop. I'm worried about rebooting on the off chance it won't load anymore. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I didn't catch it until too late because I looked away" — the time to catch it was before saying "yes to continue", `apt-get` would have told you what it was about to remove before you confirmed it...

Comment: You're right, but for some reason it only said "The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, xx.x MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `kali-desktop-gnome` is still installed, that will ensure your desktop environment is still available:

```
apt-get install kali-desktop-gnome
```

If you want to fully restore the default setup:

```
apt-get install kali-linux kali-desktop-live kali-desktop-gnome kali-linux-full
```

will ensure the default "Kali full" set of packages is installed.

Comment: I tried it, I'll paste the terminal input/output. It's petty long.

Comment: apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  0trace acccheck ace-voip afflib-tools aircrack-ng amap apache-users apktool
  arp-scan arping arpwatch asleap atftpd automater autopsy axel
  backdoor-factory bbqsql bdfproxy bed beef-xss binwalk blindelephant bluelog
  blueranger bluesnarfer bluez-hcidump braa btscanner bulk-extractor bully
  burpsuite cabextract cadaver casefile castxml cdpsnarf.......

Comment: over 14,000 chars too long. it was cut. here's the rest that is important:                                                                                               Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@kali:~# apt-get install kali-linux kali-desktop-live kali-desktop-gnome kali-linux-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kali-linux
E: Unable to locate package kali-desktop-gnome
E: Unable to locate package kali-linux-full

Comment: That's very odd, unless you're running an old version of Kali — all these packages come from [`kali-meta`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/kali-meta) which is definitely available in Sana and Kali rolling. You might need to [check your repositories](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories).